Translation syntax in SLIM view incorrect?
I have the following slim view:
/ app/views/registrations/new.html.slim

= render Forms::Headers::StandardComponent.new(header: t('users.registrations.new.header'))

= form_with model: @user, local: true, class: 'mt-8 space-y-6' do |form|
  = render Forms::Notifications::StandardErrorNotificationComponent.new(
      errors: form.object.errors,
      notification: t('users.registrations.new.prohibited_user_from_being_saved')
    )

  = render FormFieldComponent.new(form: form, label: t('users.registrations.new.email'), name: :email, type: 'email', required: true)
  = render FormFieldComponent.new(form: form, label: t('users.registrations.new.password'), name: :password, type: 'password', required: true)
  = render FormFieldComponent.new(form: form, label: t('users.registrations.new.password_confirmation'), name: :password_confirmation, type: 'password', required: true)

  .flex.items-center.justify-between
    = render Forms::Buttons::Submit::StandardComponent.new(label: t('users.registrations.new.submit'))

  .flex.items-center.justify-between.mt-4
    = render Forms::Buttons::Cancel::StandardComponent.new(label: t('users.registrations.new.cancel'), path: root_path)

My locale file:
# config/locales/users/registrations.en.yml
# Used in: app/views/users/registrations/new.html.slim
en:
  users:
    registrations:
      new:
        header: "Sign Up"
        email: "Email"
        password: "Password"
        password_confirmation: "Password Confirmation"
        submit: "Sign Up"
        cancel: "Cancel"
        already_have_an_account: "Already have an account?"
        prohibited_user_from_being_saved: "prohibited this user from being saved"

When I click on the Sign Up button, I get an error message:
Showing /Users/joseph/app/views/registrations/new.html.slim where line #8 raised:

Expected attribute
  /Joseph/app/views/registrations/new.html.slim, Line 8, Column 22
notification: t('users.registrations.new.prohibited_user_from_being_saved')
                ^

Any ideas?

Have you tried putting = message on a separate line from the li ?  Indented, of course.

what is suspicious to me is that apparently the translation on line 3 works and it only breaks on line 8. Does line 3 indeed work correctly? That translation file is bigger than that, right? Is the line 3 translation also in the file? Please provide a bigger snippet of the file or the whole file if it's not too big. I suspect some typos or yaml errors (duplicate key or such).

@SiimLiiser Yes, it seems as if line 3 works for,  because I can see the header. It's only when I click on Sign Up that I get the error message. The translation file is really small as I'm starting out with the app. I will post the entire file

What's more pertinent here is a stack trace.

The error "Expected attribute", indicates that this is not a translation error, but a slim syntax error.
If you use multiline ruby, Slim might misunderstand if the next line is supposed to be Slim or ruby. I suspect this is the case here.
Add a - in front of the ruby lines that don't have a = in front.
Alternatively, add a backslash \ at the end of the preceding line.
See the docs for more: https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/slim/frames#control_code_

I broke one line into three, and slim did not like it. I put it all on the same line. The - in slim means that you're executing rails code. The = means you're pushing output.

Yes. Exactly. The line notification: t('users.registrations.new.prohibited_user_from_being_saved') is ruby code that is not pushing output. It should be prefixed with -. Sometimes slim is smart enough to imply it from context. Sometimes not. Did you try adding a - to it or commented without trying?

I put it on the same line.

And? Is it working or are you still getting an error? Is it the same error? Please update the question if it's still an issue.
